# Which program should I use to find moment of inertia of complex sections?

Tags: autocad, cross-section

It is an aluminium section for a mullion and transom and the autocad drawing I have is very complex and I tried using autocad mechanical but it does not work as I am not able to select the area as it is very complex. The properties say that the selection is a closed area however on going to content>calculations>moment of inertia, or using aminertia, I cannot select the enclosed area.

Please give me an application where I can find the moment of inertia and corresponding values.

Comment: perhaps divide into smaller parts and then combine the answers, much as we used to do with pencil and paper...

Comment: Do it manually. Probably more reliable.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, one program I found that can help calculate the different properties of a section is "ShapeDesigner SaaS"

the reason that I am not doing it manually is that I would have to break it into at least 35+ parts. This program calculates it in a few moments. Hope this helps some people.